# Show div when mouse hover result from select input

Tags: jquery

I have select input with some result and "idresult" for each.
I would like to show with jquery div 1 when the mouse is hover idresult=1, and div 2 when the mouse is hover idresult=2 , etc... and hide last div displayed.
Any idea ?

Html script :

```
<select id="myselect">
 <option idresult="1" value="Value test 1">TEST 1</option>
 <option idresult="2"  value="Value test 2">TEST 2</option>
 <option idresult="3"  value="Value test 3">TEST 3</option>
</select>

<div id="1" style="display:none;">Div with information for idresult=1</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none;">Div with information for idresult=2</div>
<div id="3" style="display:none;">Div with information for idresult=3</div>
```

Jquery script :

```
$('#myselect').on('mouseover', function () {
    var myidselect=$(this).attr("idresult");
    $(myidselect).show(); // display the div in relation with select result
});
```

Comment: Don't make up random attributes. If you need a custom attribute, use a `data-` attribute. Ex `data-idresult="3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off don't clutter the DOM with random attributes, use `data-` instead.

Finally, you're getting the string value, but never passing it as a valid selector to Sizzle (jQuery's selector engine). You need to prepend the string with `#` as follows:

```js
$('#myselect').on('mouseover', function () {
    var myidselect = $(this).children('option:selected').data("idresult");
    $('#'+myidselect).show().siblings('div').hide(); // display the div in relation with select result
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
 <option data-idresult="1" value="Value test 1">TEST 1</option>
 <option data-idresult="2"  value="Value test 2">TEST 2</option>
 <option data-idresult="3"  value="Value test 3">TEST 3</option>
</select>

<div id="1" style="display:none;">Div with information for idresult=1</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none;">Div with information for idresult=2</div>
<div id="3" style="display:none;">Div with information for idresult=3</div>
```

Note that we need to use `$(this).children('option:selected').data("idresult")` since the `data-` attributes are assigned to `<option>` elements within the `<select>`.

Notice also that we use `siblings('div').hide()` to hide the previously shown `<div>` elements. But you may wish to identify these information divs using a classname or some other mechanism for better portability.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I use .selectpicker with bootstrap and your proposal does'nt works with that. Any idea ?